# Different execution plans in SQL Server for same query but different offset

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, full-text-search, sql-server-2019

I am doing performance experiments regarding the fulltext search feature of Microsoft SQL Server using the [stackoverflow database](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange).

I have a (seemingly simple) query that results in different execution plans (and vastly different run times) depending simply on the specified offset value.

This version of the query (offset 0) is slow:

```
SELECT Comments.Id, Comments.PostId, Comments.Score, Comments.Text, Comments.CreationDate, Comments.UserId
FROM Comments   
WHERE contains(Text,'SQL')
AND contains(Text,'Server')
AND contains(Text,'2016')
AND Score IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Score DESC
OFFSET 0 rows
FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

```
(100 rows affected)
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2159279, logical reads 4325811, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Comments'. Scan count 1, logical reads 12299107, physical reads 1661, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 2466352, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 43515 ms,  elapsed time = 23474 ms.
```

Execution plan:
[image]

This version of the query (offset 2000), however, completes within fractions of a second:

```
SELECT Comments.Id, Comments.PostId, Comments.Score, Comments.Text, Comments.CreationDate, Comments.UserId
FROM Comments   
WHERE contains(Text,'SQL')
AND contains(Text,'Server')
AND contains(Text,'2016')
AND Score IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Score DESC
OFFSET 2000 rows
FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

```
(100 rows affected)
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Comments'. Scan count 0, logical reads 11853, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 30, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 47 ms,  elapsed time = 20 ms.
```

Execution plan:
[image]

If, in the first query, I replace the `ORDER BY / OFFSET 0 / FETCH NEXT 100` by a simple `TOP 100`, but of course, this is not a viable solution in practice, because I want that specific (and deterministic) order:

```
(100 rows affected)
Table 'Comments'. Scan count 0, logical reads 821, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 107, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 6 ms.
```

[image]

More info about the data and schema:

- There are 74,428,966 rows in the table Comments.
- Here is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Comments](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PostId] [int] NULL,
    [Score] [int] NULL,
    [Text] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CreationDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Comments] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

- There is a full text search index on the Text column
- Here are the other indexes:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Comments_CreationDate] ON [dbo].[Comments]
(
    [CreationDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Comments_PostId] ON [dbo].[Comments]
(
    [PostId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Comments_Score] ON [dbo].[Comments]
(
    [Score] ASC,
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Comments_UserId] ON [dbo].[Comments]
(
    [UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

My question is: Why are the execution plans different and what would be the recommended way to improve the situation, such that both queries use the fast execution plan?

*Addendum*:

Based on one of Nikitas suggestions, I tried an altered version of the two queries.

Slow:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT Id   
FROM Comments   
WHERE contains(Text,'SQL')
AND contains(Text,'Server')
AND contains(Text,'2016')
AND Score IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Score DESC
OFFSET 0 rows
FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
)
SELECT Comments.Id, Comments.PostId, Comments.Score, Comments.Text, Comments.CreationDate, Comments.UserId
FROM Comments
JOIN CTE on Comments.Id = CTE.Id
ORDER BY Comments.score DESC
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

```
(100 rows affected)
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2009360, logical reads 4025794, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Comments'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3915, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 2125 ms,  elapsed time = 2117 ms.
```

[image: Execution plan]

Fast (same query, except OFFSET=2000):

```
(100 rows affected)
Table 'Comments'. Scan count 9, logical reads 131034, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 1304, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 1548 ms,  elapsed time = 217 ms.
```

[image: Execution plan]

Comment: Does the problem still exist? Obviously, the first query was run on outdated statistics (look at estimated/actual rows on the first screen).

Comment: I have rerun the queries and updated the query plans in the question. Although the query with offset 0 is faster than before, it is still significantly slower than the other one; also, the estimates are also still way off. I executed both queries immediately after each other. There are no other queries (or inserts, deletes, updates...) going on.

Comment: could you please fix the question description? you use the same offset for both cases and I don't see the first execution plan

Comment: You can't remove the `ORDER BY` without also removing the `OFFSET`. So can you show the query / plan without the `ORDER BY` _and_ the `OFFSET`? Also to avoid things like key lookups, see this post, which describes why you shouldn't just use `SELECT * ... OFFSET`. https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch

Answer (score 1):

Different offset means different number of rows should be matched - 100 in the first case and 2100 in the second one. In the second case SQL Server may choose more expensive parallel execution plan but it may work faster by different reasons. For example, because of statistics misestimation the first query may work much slower than expected and it would be better to choose the second plan for it from the very beginning. To do this you could parametrize your query and use hint OPTIMIZE FOR @offset = 2000.
Also with proper indexing it may has a sense to use a subquery to select required row ids with offset first, and after that join other fields to these 100 ids rather than SELECT * with offset 2000 (this way SQL Server may need to sort a lot of large rows before it be able to omit first 2000 of them).
Please check the following query (for both offsets and with statistics time, io on enabled):

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT id   
FROM Comments   
WHERE contains(Text,'SQL')
AND contains(Text,'Server')
AND contains(Text,'2016')
AND Score IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Score DESC
OFFSET 0 rows
FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
)
SELECT Comments.* 
FROM Comments
JOIN CTE on Comments.id = CTE.id
ORDER BY Comments.score DESC
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
;
```

Comment: Thanks for your ideas, @Nikita. Making the offset a variable and using the "optimize for" does indeed result in the quicker execution plan, but I am not sure if this solution will be applicable in the context of an application later on. It seems quite fragile and difficult to determine the right offset value to optimize for (here, it seems to be values >= 63). The CTE also made the slower query (offset 0, not optimized for larger offset) quicker, but it is still significantly slower than the one with the higher offset (or optimization).

Comment: this CTE should make the second query faster too

Comment: also you can try to save execution plan and use "USE PLAN N'your_xml_plan'" hint (or do the same using plan guide) but it may be not good idea too because this way you force SQL Server to use the same plan for any parameters

Comment: I added the query plans and statistics output for your CTE suggestions. Regarding USE PLAN, it seems that this hint is not compatible with full-text search: ```Cannot execute query because USE PLAN hint conflicts with use of distributed query or full-text operations. Consider removing USE PLAN hint.```

Comment: @Hi4s, yes. Attempt failed:) sorry, I forgot about fill-text.

Comment: the problem is that according to existing stats SQL Server determines that the fulltext search should return a lot of rows and it hopes that it will be able to find 100 of such rows fast enough reading score index row by row and checking if their ids exists in fulltext search result. Please check the estimated number of rows for index seek on Comments.Comments_Score. It should be much less than number of rows estimated for fulltext search in the second query. But in fact its assumption was too optimistic.

Comment: Indeed, for the index seek in my original (slow) query: ```Actual Number of Rows: 2162401```; ```Estimated Number of Rows: 89331,1```. Similarly for the CTE version: ```Actual Number of Rows: 2009360```; ```Estimated Number of Rows: 89331,1```.

Comment: @Hi4s, yes, it should be the same. I described the reason why it works slow (in both cases, with CTE and without it). The reason why I suggested to use CTE that the query with CTE works a bit faster because it doesn't need to run 200 000 key lookups when OFFSET = 0 and it doesn't need to sort large rows when OFFSET = 2000.